# Need permissions changed of a folder + files together using Ansible synchronize module

Tags: directory, ansible, permissions, file-permissions, rsync

I allow the user the option to enter 3 digit number for setting permission of files or folders being transferred say `-e myperm: 775`

I use ansible where I provide `rsync_opts: --chmod:F775` (synchronize module) to change the permission of the transferred file/folder on the destination to 775

```
- name: sync file
  synchronize:
    src: /tmp/file.py
    dest: /home/myuser/file.py
    mode: push
    rsync_opts:
      - "--chmod=F0{{ myperm }}"
```

Above works fine for files; however, the same does not work for transferring folders say when     `src: /tmp/folder`

I tried `--chmod=D0{{ myperm }},F0{{ myperm }}` in ansible but it translates to  `--chmod=D0775  F0775` and gives this error:

```
msg": "Unexpected remote arg: user@desthost:/tmp/folder\nrsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1344) [sender=3.1.2]\n", "rc": 1}
```

Can you please suggest `rsync_opts` with variable `myperm` for changing permissions of both files and folders?

Any other solution will also be fine.

Comment: rsync allows multiple chmod options, have you tried with : `rsync_opts:
 - "--chmod=F0{{ myperm }}" - "--chmod=D0{{ myperm }}"` ?

Comment: @guido it still does not work. See output: 
`failed: [desthost] (item=/tmp/folder) => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh=/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null - \"--chmod=D0777\" - \"--chmod=F0777\" --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L destuser@desthost:/tmp/folder /web/playbooks/filecopy/tmpfiles/107/", "item": "/tmp/folder", "msg": "rsync: - \"--chmod=D0777\" - \"--chmod=F0777\": unknown option\nrsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1568) [client=3.1.2]\n", "rc": 1}`

Comment: `"rsync: Invalid argument passed to --chmod (F0777 - --chmod=D0777)\nrsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1568) [client=3.1.2]\n", "rc": 1}`

Comment: ah sorry, the two chmod items were supposed to go on different lines (forming an array); or, you can use the compact syntax `rsync_opts: [ '--chmod=F0{{ myperm }}', '--chmod=D0{{ myperm }}' ]`

Comment: @guido with new different lines I was able to get this to work for both files and folders. Can you please post it as an answer for me to accept ? Great help by the way!!

Comment: you are welcome, sure will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a problem in parsing the comma separated argument when the module generates the rsync command line, however, since rsync allows multiple chmod options, you can rewrite your task as:

```
[..]
rsync_opts:  
  - "--chmod=F0{{ myperm }}"
  - "--chmod=D0{{ myperm }}"
```